# AngularJS Populate Data in Directive from Rest Call with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts, typescript

Using AngularJS and Typescript (Not to worry if you do not know TypeScript, an AngularJS proposal would do me) I am trying to create a directive for highcharts that has dynamic data that is populated by a call to a service that gets the chart data (via REST)

My html looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="request in controller.chartRequests">
            <bar-chart id = "snapshotChart"
                    get-chart-data = "controller.getChartData(request)" // Some other attributes />
            </bar-chart>
</div>
```

My hope is to dynamically draw the charts based on the number of stored requests I have in my controller.

The request object is used by the 'chartDataService' as shown below.

It returns the data as an array - eg: [1,12] and I resolve as a promise

```
public getChartData = (chartRequest) => {

        let deferred = this.$q.defer();
        this.chartDataService.dispatchCommand(chartRequest).then(
            this.returnChartData // just returns a series
        ).then((series) => {
            // This populates fine e.g [1,12]
            deferred.resolve(series);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };


constructor() {
        let directive:ng.IDirective = {};
        directive.restrict = 'E';
        directive.replace = true;
        directive.scope = {
            getChartData: '&',
            /** Other attributes **/
        };

directive.link = (scope, element, attrs) => {

        let highchartsOptions:HighchartsOptions = {

            /**
            * Some Highcharts config this all works fine
            **/

            series: [
                {
                    data: scope.getChartData()
                }
            ]
        };

        let chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
            highchartsOptions
        );

        }
```

I have tried a scope.watch on getChartData() but this cause an infinite loop of requests it seems.

Not sure if anyone can help me out here - I may be approaching this problem in the wrong way.

Any help much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Couldn't you load your data first  - as a variable, and then create your chart with this data?

Comment: Hi, Yes I could do this - And normally I would - But in this instance I would like to fetch the data dynamically on a per request basis.

Comment: If you would like to add your data dynamically, ,maybe you can use addSeries and addPoint methods of Highcharts?

Comment: Hi, I actually went back to your first suggestion and passed the preloaded data directly to the directive and I create the chart in there.